# Load the linux server

Tags: linux

I want to load up a linux server so swap space gets used. Is there any tool that I can run on the server so swap starts getting used ? Also, is there a script or tool that I can run that will increase the kernel memory usage. I am doing some profiling on my linux server (centOS) so need to artifically load the system.

Comment: You could code a tiny *C* program which `malloc`-s a huge zone and fill it. It is faster than asking the question :-)

Comment: I  dont know C. I am familiar with shell scripting. So wondering if I can run a script of some sort.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: Excellent suggestion.
user238021, you can install it with "yum install stress" (I hope it's available on CentOS. At least it is on Debian.)

Comment: @tiktak, thanks for mentioning abt stress. I am going to see if it is there on centos. If I run it ,how do i know the kernel memory is being used ?

Comment: @user238021 Well, "stress" is good to "Load the linux server" (as in your title"). However, if you want to stress the kernel, you probably have to write a custom kernel module or something like that. On Google I found that the tool "slabtop" will tell you info about how your kernel is running. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python -c 'a = range(some_huge_number); raw_input()'` can chew up lots of memory, and will hold it until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Start with smallish numbers (say 1000000 or so) and ramp up, watching memory carefully to make sure you don't crush your system too badly.

Comment: Sweet. I see swap space being used now when I gave the number as 10000000 in the python line. Does it also increase the kernel memory usage ? currently, in cat /proc/meminfo, I see these lines   Slab:            1398736 kB                                                                   KernelStack:        2408 kB                                                                   PageTables:        45852 kB                                                                   Does  these 3 add to kernel memory usage ?

Comment: This code shouldn't affect the kernel, but obviously memory will need to be allocated in order to hold the huge structure.